# Using hardware layers while animating view

Tags: android, android-animation

I have been trying to fix a couple of dropped frames in an animation the past couple hours. The first time i run the animation i drop ~5 frames (subsequent animations on the same view are super smooth). I thought i would try using hardware layers while animating but it did not work (no difference in the animation), using a software layer does fix the the issue with dropped frames.

However, when using a software layer i get the feeling (no scientific test, might just be in my head) that the animation is not quite as smooth as using a hardware layer / using no layer (on the animation after the first one that lags of course).

So i am wondering how i could fix this / what i am doing wrong. I could render the animation using a software layer the first time and disable layers on subsequent animations but that seems like a bad work around.

Here is the code i use:

```
    final View v = .....;

    v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    v.buildLayer();

    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 180);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(250);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Float animatedValue = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.setRotation(animatedValue);
        }
    });
    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        }
    });
    anim.start();
```

Comment: Some more info. I am building the layer when the view visibility is View.INVISIBLE. if i instead use v.setAlpha(0) there is not longer any lag in the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the layer to `HARDWARE` should actually improve the smootheness of animations drastically. If you test your app in the emulator, check "Use host GPU" in the virtual device settings to benefit from hardware acceleration.